# Quadratic variation of a square integrable continuous martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Is the total variation of the quadratic variation process of a square integrable right continuous martingale bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the quadratic variation process is non-decreasing, its total variation is equal to its value and the quadratic variation does not need to be bounded, although it will have finite expectation and hence be a.s. finite.  For example, let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion, $\tau := \inf\{t : |B_t| = 1\}$, and $M_t := B_{t \wedge \tau}$.  Then $M$ is square integrable (in fact $M$ is bounded) and continuous, but $\langle M,M \rangle_t = t \wedge \tau$ and $\tau$ is not bounded.

Comment: Does that mean that when we define the integral with respect to a quadratic variation it is defined a.e? Since I guess the integral we consider here is normal Lebesgue-Stieljis  integral

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  To clarify though, "a.e." refers to $\omega$, not $t$, i.e. we have for almost every $\omega$ that the integral is defined for all $t > 0$.